# Populating a Dictionary with an Update Cursor "Typeerror: 'Dict' Object Is Not Callable"

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I'm getting the following error `"Type Error: 'dict' object is not callable"`, with the code below:

```
import arcpy

def printDict(dictionary, printCount=False):
    for key in dictionary:
        arcpy.AddMessage(key + ": " + dictionary[key])
    if printCount is True:
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(len(dictionary)))

pld3GDB = 'C:\\Users\\bro81520\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep\\PLDV3_SPC_ODN_315_25Sep.gdb\\WO_HIERARCHY'
fdaAREA = 'C:\\Users\\bro81520\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Default.gdb\\FDA_AREA'

d = dict()  # VENDOR_WO_ID : NFID

fields1 = ['VENDOR_WO_ID', 'NFID', 'ISFDA'] 
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pld3GDB, fields1) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[2] == "Y":
            d[row[0]] = row[1]

# print dictionary
printDict(d, printCount=True)

fields2 = ['bv_workorderid', 'bv_nfid']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fdaAREA, fields2) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in d:
            row[1] = d[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I've looked at the following resources, but haven't deciphered exactly what is wrong:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605525/typeerror-dict-object-is-not-callable-while-using-dict`

`https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198770/creating-a-dict-with-search-cursor`

Comment: Is that your entire code?  Have you used `dict` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: I added the rest of my code in, figured the beginning part was pretty trivial.

Comment: Does your code work as expected using `d = {}`?

Comment: If I change that I get `"Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 12)"`

Comment: Hmmm... `d = {}` should be valid syntax

Comment: When I copied and pasted it from your post it worked, no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect somewhere along the way, the built-in [dict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) got set to something else (probably like below), and is no longer the object you think it is.

```
d = dict()        # new dictionary
print(d)          # it works!

{}    

dict = {}         # dict isn't dict() anymore
d = dict()        # error!

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e3c238d66cd2> in <module>
----> 1 d = dict()

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is generated when we try to call a dictionary using invalid methods. As shown in the example below.

**Example:**

```
# Creating dictionary 'MyDict'
MyDict= {
'car' : 'Honda city',
'type': 'sedan',
'color' : 'Blue'
}

# Printing Dictionary
print(MyDict())

# Checking length of dictionary
print("length of the dictionary :",len(MyDict))
```

Output:

```
File "nterror.py", line 9, in <module>
print(MyDict( ))
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

[Read here in details](https://www.stechies.com/typeerror-dict-object-not-callable/)